How does chrome's "new third-party cookie experience" affect my website?
Recently, I've started seeing this warning in the Chrome console:

Chrome is moving towards a new experience that allows users to choose to browse without third-party cookies.

I checked the settings:

The rest of the cookie settings with the "testing" tag are marked as default, and in Chrome settings I only have cookies blocked in incognito mode.
So, if I'm not in the 1% that's testing the cookie phaseout, what is causing this warning, does it have any affects on my site today, and what can I do to resolve it?
